# How to get elements from a double[] Array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I list the elements from a double[] Array. Here is my init and assignment.

```
final int nr=10;

double[] cArray= new double[100];
System.arraycopy(Global.ArrayAlpha, 0, cArray, Global.ArrayBeta.length, Global.ArrayAlpha.length);

for(int i=0;i< nr;i++){
    System.println( cArray?????);
}
```

A simiple question, I know , but all attempts have been unsuccessful. 
The program is java and I get the following error when i use cArray.get(k)

Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type

Comment: What kinda errors are u getting? is Global.ArrayAlpha the same length as cArray (100) ?

Comment: And the programming language is...?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (double x : cArray) System.out.println("" + x);
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) System.out.println("" + cArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (double d : cArray) {
  System.out.println(d);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(cArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array element access `[]`, i.e.

```
 System.out.println(cArray[i]);
```

An alternative way is foreach loop:

```
 for(double currentDouble : cArray) { /* use currentDouble here */ }
```

Also note, that `println` is a function of `System.out` (the standard output) rather than `System`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are *not* objects. If you want to get a specified element from an array use the following syntax: `myArray[123]` to get 123<sup>th</sup> element from 0-based index.

Comment: Actually arrays ARE objects and myArray[123] will give you the 124th element (including element 0).